# Reset token do not work sometimes?

Tags: asp.net-identity

On a mvc site using asp.net identity, my users are complaining that sometimes the password reset function do not work. All I do is generate a password reset token using `GeneratePasswordResetToken(userId)` and sent to their email with a link. I then use this token calling `ResetPasswordAsync(userId, token, newPassword)`

I cannot reproduce this but I can attest that, sometimes, on some users machines, the ResetPassword returns "InvalidToken". Any clue on what could be happening here? I read somewhere that those tokens are time-based so maybe they are invalid after some time?

If this is so, what would be the default time duration of the asp.net identity token and it is possible to increase it?

**edit 1**
I did a test on this and detected that before 3 minutes the token still works but not after 5 minutes. So I am guessing that it is valid for 5 minutes. The question is if that is possible to increase it or remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just found out the answer. The ApplicationUserManager have `UserTokenProvider` on where we can pass a IUserTokenProvider where we can set the default expire time:

```
manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User, int>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity")) { TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1) };
```